# 301 Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect my website to a new domain name but I want it to also redirect all of the pages. I want www.myoldsite.com/ to redirect to www.mynewsite.com/ but I also want all of the pages to redirect.

For example: www.myoldsite.com/faq to redirect to www.mynewsite.com/faq and so forth and so on. I know how to do it by doing each individual page but I have a lot of pages. How do I rewrite the 301 for it to basically change the root domain name but keep the directories and pages the same? Thanks a million!

Comment: So keep the following url, but keep the domain name?

Comment: I am changing www.thefloridamovers.com to www.tfmmovers.com but I also want all pages to transfer. For example I want http://thefloridamovers.com/moving-services/ to redirect to http://tfmmovers.com/moving-services/

and so forth and so on without having to manually put each link in htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this in the htaccess file in your old domain's document root:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.mynewsite.com/
```

If both your old site and new site share the same document root, then you need mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myoldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But that just takes it to the root when I add the mod_rewrite. For example, when I go to thefloridamovers.com/moving-services it takes me to tfmmovers.com and I want it to take me to tfmmovers.com/moving-services

Comment: Nevermind. Wow. I didn't realize that the first one was all that I needed to do. I thought it was more than that. You got it Jon Lin. Thanks!